# Custom style for edited row GridView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Im looking for styling the row that's being edited in my GridView.

I know how to change the background colour and the font, but what i need is it to look like it's over the grid, like with a shadow, the edited row must be really highlighted.

My styles.css:

```
.grid_normalRow /*on mouse out event*/
{
       background-color:white;
}
.grid_highlightedRow /*on mouse over event*/
{
       background-color:aqua;
}
.grid_editedRow /*on row editing event - The one i need to change */
{
       background-color:yellow;
       font-weight: bold;
       height: 30px;

}
```

I can't find the apropiate css style to acomplish my requirement.

Comment: box-shadow ? have you tried it ?

Comment: yes i did, but it's not making the shadow effect in the Grid..

Comment: for an outside shadow(if hidden by boxes around), you can add : position:relative if all element are statics, if already positioned, increase the z-index value :) do you a jsfiddle or codepen of html/css rendered ?

Comment: z-index was a good try, but didnt work either.. maybe it's the grid that doesnt allow some styles..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about this method?

EDIT: If you are using a table, you can make Box Shadow work by adding `display: block` on the `tr`'s. I updated the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/wilman/pen/BKNJXJ) to show how it works.

```css
.grid_editedRow
/*The one i need to change*/

{
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
.grid_normalRow
/*on mouse out event*/

{
  /* adding bg color messes with the shadow effect */
  /* background-color:white; */
}
.grid_highlightedRow
/*on mouse over event*/

{
  background-color: aqua;
}
tr {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="grid_normalRow">
    <td>yet</td>
    <td>another</td>
    <td>grid</td>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="grid_editedRow">
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>How</td>
    <td>Are</td>
    <td>you?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="grid_normalRow">
    <td>yet</td>
    <td>another</td>
    <td>grid</td>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="grid_highlightedRow">
    <td>yet</td>
    <td>another</td>
    <td>grid</td>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can see the resulting effect in this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/wilman/pen/BKNJXJ)

Comment: The shadow doesnt display in the grid row, if i use the same style in a button or a div it's ok, but it's not working for the grid row.

Comment: That style is exactly what im looking for, but it's not working either!

Comment: It's difficult to know why it's not working without seeing a portion of the HTML. Can you add more details about the generated HTML?

Comment: Check: http://postimg.org/image/k280nuxeb/ and http://postimg.org/image/40cnnb4il/. to see the result.. The generated HTML is not really readable as it has a lot of autogenerated code..

Comment: I see. Maybe adding `display: block` to all, .grid_normalRow, .grid_editedRow and .grid_highlightedRow will fix the issue. It's critical that every row in the grid has such property.

Comment: Display block almost did the trick!! It has the shadow effect now, but the whole row is staying in the first column, check http://postimg.org/image/jxu2u6ozr/

Comment: The help I can give here is a bit limited as I can't see the actual code but at least I could reproduce your problem in this Codepen (look at line 23 in the CSS): http://codepen.io/wilman/pen/zqvvBN. It seems like not all the rows have the `display: block` property enabled. Maybe another style is overriding the `display` property of some rows?

Answer (score 0):

first in your gridview row edit function you set the css of the row.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.EditRowStyle.CssClass = "EditRow";
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

then you set the css to

```
    .EditRow 
    {
    background-color:yellow;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 4px #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 30px;
    }
```

you can play around a  little with the border-radius and the box-shadow values to make it the way you like the most

Comment: That style is not working in the GridView row.. only the background-color efect is visible..

Comment: @DiegoS then something else must be wrong because its working. " Are you using the RowEditing event of the gridview ?"maybe you overwrite the settings somewhere else. try it on a new form and a new gridview and you will see it works